# Matching records between two excel workbooks

Tags: excel

Excel file 'A' has 650 rows, each containing a unique ID code in column A. I want to find those 650 unique ID codes in Excel file 'B' which has 2500 rows and the same unique identifier code column. I want to return these records to a new sheet. I have pretty much tried every lookup, match and index and can't seem to get what I am looking for.

Comment: Try using `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Can you combine the data in one file?

Comment: Can you post at least one of your formulas? Preferably, we'd like to see any and all attempts, and notes on what did/didn't work.

Comment: Will there be multiple rows in file 'B' that match a specific ID in file 'A'? If so, it is easy enough to write an Excel VBA macro to go down column A of file 'A', search for each entry in file 'B' and store the results on a sheet either in one of the two files or in a new file. Do some research, write some code, show us the code and we'll help further.

Comment: You don't say if the same ID can exist multiple times in A or if the same ID can exist multiple times in B and you don't say if you want the records from A on the new sheet or if you want the records from B on the new sheet and you don't say which file you want the new sheet in and there are other details missing as well.

Comment: VLOOKUP would work if you wanted the first occurance - but it doesn't work if B has the same ID multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a macro instead of a worksheet formula then this is quite easy to achieve.

Notes:

- assumption: both sets of data are in the same workbook on worksheets called A and B respectively
- assumption: the column to be matched is called ID on both worksheets
- assumption: the output should be placed on a worksheet called C
- the workbook must be saved as a .xlsm file before running the macro

Go to the Visual Basic Editor with Alt-F11, choose Insert > Module then paste in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cross_ref()

Dim cn As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With cn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;IMEX=1;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT [B$].* " & _
    "FROM [A$] INNER JOIN [B$] " & _
    "ON [A$].[ID] = [B$].[ID];", cn

Dim sFieldName As String
Dim fld As Object
Dim i As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    i = 0
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld
    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Now save the workbook and run the macro by putting the cursor anywhere in the macro and clicking the Play button (or pressing F5)

The macro joins up all of the rows from A and B (the `FROM [A$] INNER JOIN [B$]` part) that have matching ID values (the `ON [A$].[ID] = [B$].[ID]` part) and outputs all of the rows from B that matched (the `SELECT [B$].*` part). The rest of the macro just sets up the connection, outputs the data and tidies up at the end